# System of equations with symetric fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

How to solve this system of equations? I tried to add and substract first and second equation but without any result.

$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x}{y} + \dfrac{y}{z} + \dfrac{z}{x} = 3\\
\dfrac{y}{x} + \dfrac{z}{y} + \dfrac{x}{z} = 3\\
x + y + z = 3 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT :

Setting $\frac xy=a,\frac yz=b,\frac zx=c$ gives
$$abc=1$$
$$a+b+c=3$$
$$\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c=3\iff ab+bc+ca=3$$
So, $a,b,c$ are the roots of $X^3-3X^2+3X-1=0$.